# Display time in current locale using Calendar

Tags: android, calendar

How can I display the time  in the current app locale using Calendar?

For instance I'd like "14:35" in french, and "2:35 pm" in english.

When my default locale is french, I get the time in english:

```
Calendar cal;
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());   
String displayTime = cal.getTime(); //Wed Mar 28 13:41:00 HAEC 2012
```

From the doc, Calendar is "locale aware". Do I have to set the locale manually? How?

I could use `SimpleDateFormat`, but I'd have to set a pattern with the hour format as 'h' or 'k' manually according to whether I want hours in day or am/pm.

Basically: is there any locale-aware method to get the time as hours:minutes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically: is there any locale-aware method to get the time as hours:minutes?

No, but you can ask android if the mobile is set in 24hours format or AM/PM and compile the patter for the `SimpleDateFormat` accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
cal.getTime().toLocaleString();
```